# ayuda con python y pycrypto

Tags: python, python-2.7

mi dolor de cabeza es este  quiero hacer un programa que me encripte ciertos archivos y luego borre la version original, por que lo he intentado solo me funciona con un solo archivo y crea uno nuevo, yo trabajo con archivos delicados y cuando termino de moficarlos es encriptar y borrar la version sin encriptar.

```
> home = expanduser("~")
```

Aqui comienza el codigo

```
## def encrypt(key, filename):
    chunksize = 64*1024
    outputFile = "(encrypted)"+filename
    filesize = str(os.path.getsize(filename)).zfill(16)
    IV = ''

    for i in range(16):
        IV += chr(random.randint(0, 0xFF))

    encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)

    with open(filename, 'rb') as infile:
        with open(outputFile, 'wb') as outfile:
            outfile.write(filesize)
            outfile.write(IV)

            while True:
                chunk = infile.read(chunksize)

                if len(chunk) == 0:
                    break
                elif len(chunk) % 16 != 0:
                    chunk += ' ' * (16 - (len(chunk) % 16))

                outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk))
```

Este codigo me lo encontre en un foro ya que no encuentro nada relevante en pycrypto

```
> encrypt(getKey(password), lista_archivos)
```

Con esto llamo para poder encriptar lo malo es que arriba solo aceptan un archivo y yo tengo una lista

```
> 
> lista_archivos =  [ [os.path.join(root,file),root.split(path)[1]] for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path)
                    for file in files if os.path.splitext(file)[-1] in extensiones ]
```

Asi es como cifro la llave

```
password = "xx"

> def getKey(password):

    hasher = SHA256.new(password)
    return hasher.digest()
```

lo estoy resumiendo lo mas que puedo

bueno el caso es que, la lista recorre todos los archivos con extensiones .xx, y luego me lo almacena en una lista yo quiero encriptar esos archivos y luego borrar el original, arriba el codigo de encriptar solo me permite encriptar un solo archivo, si alguien me ayuda se los agradecería mucho .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu método `encrypt(key, filename)` solo procesa un archivo.

Si quieres que procese una lista deberías agregar un bucle en el cuerpo de la función. O directamente invocarlo así:

```
for f in lista_archivos:
    encrypt(getKey(password), f)
```

Comment: Hola @jayson-jose si esta o cualquier otra respuesta ha resuelto su problema, por favor considera [aceptarla](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) clicando la marca de check (en forma de V debajo de la puntuación de la respuesta). Esto indica a la comunidad que has encontrado una solución y de paso os dará reputación a ambos (a tí y quien ha respondido). Por supuesto, no tienes ninguna obligación de hacerlo.